# How can I improve my wireless keyboard & mouse reception?

Tags: technology

So I have a logitech wireless keyboard/mouse combo that I love the layout of. It's very ergonomic and I would prefer to keep using it. The problem is is that it only comes in wireless, and my pc is setting at just the very edge of it's reliable range. Sometimes signal drops out and I miss letters, or it takes a long time for letters to get there. I don't want to rearrange my desk for what should be wireless, but at the same time, I'd like to keep the keyboard. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most people think of wireless as no wires coming from the computer, I realized, my computer needs some cables (power, video, network) so one more isn't going to hurt. I got a USB extension cable, and plugged the wireless receiver into that. I now have the cable with the receiver taped the underside of my desk right under where my keyboard sits (If you have a glass desk you may need to get more creative if you want to hide it). For all intents and purposes, my keyboard and mouse are wireless, but I still get great reception.

Comment: That's just what I wanted to suggest. I didn't even make a big effort as you to hide it and just put the end of the USB extension cord with the wireless receiver for my mouse at the top end of my desk, so it's just inches away from the mouse.
Your thoughts are correct. Anything to reduce the distance will do the trick.